# CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i get this error on production server.
i have **Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll;
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll** these dlls in my bin folder still i get this error

Comment: Are you deploying the correct versions of the assemblies?

Comment: i am not sure...